# Spring MVC, CSS, and JavaScript is not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, spring

The CSS and JavaScript is not take effect on my page.
I googled online, people saying this is the magic, but not happening on my page.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

This is the error:

```
Nov 02, 2013 9:19:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myweb/resources/css/styles.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Nov 02, 2013 9:19:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myweb/resources/script.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Nov 02, 2013 9:19:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myweb/resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Here is the applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.peterhuang.myweb" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.peterhuang.myweb" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                ${jdbc.dialect}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                ${hibernate.show_sql}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">
                ${hibernate.format_sql}
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>my web</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This is the page got displaied:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="<spring:url value='resources/css/styles.css' />" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="<spring:url value='resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value='resources/script.js'/>"</script>     

<ul id="button">
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categoryList}">
    <li><a href="#">${category.categoryName}</a></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

The folder structure in Eclipse:

```
myweb
  |
  |
  |
  |----Java Resources
  |             |
  |             |
  |             |-----src/main/resources
  |             |                |
  |             |                |
  |             |                |------js
  |             |                |       |
  |             |                |       |-----jquery-1.10.2.min.js
  |             |                |       |
  |             |                |       |
  |             |                |       |-----script.js
  |             |                |         
  |             |                |      
  |             |                |-----css
  |             |                |      |
  |             |                |      |-----style.css
  |             |                |      |
  |             |                |      |
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Option 1**

You need one more level for "resources." The `src/main/resources` folder is Maven's root location for resources that will be included in your classpath. Do this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/resources" />
```

With this directory structure:

```
src/main/resources/resources
                       |
                       |------js
                       |
                       ...
```

**Option 2**

Or, if you'd rather move your resources to the web root, do this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />
```

...with this directory structure:

```
src/main/webapp/resources
                       |
                       |------js
                       |
                       ...
```

Comment: I did this:  put js and css folders inside here  src/main/resources/resources.    and keep the xml unchanged. the error reminds the same.

Comment: No, you have to change the xml to the example I gave if you are going to put your resources there. You can leave it unchanged if you use the second example directory structure.

Comment: I've reorganized my answer into two options. If you don't want to change your xml, use option 2.

Comment: i used option 2 it got same error :       Nov 02, 2013 11:56:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myweb/resources/css/styles.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Nov 02, 2013 11:56:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myweb/resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: I copy folder into C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\resources.    the css and javascript work now.    but is there anyway i can keep those file in my project rather than put it outside of project.

Comment: I'm afraid you might have systemic issues related to an unfamiliarity with your tools. Do you know how Eclipse and Maven work together? Your project should be a "Maven" project inside Eclipse, and all of your deployments to a WST server should be published automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two bugs:

**First**

in your jsp you used missed the js folder in the `resources/script.js` path!

Correct would be:

```
<spring:url value='resources/js/script.js'/>
```

**Second** (it is exactly what "kungfuters" has already written)

The 2. thing is that maven merge the folder: ´src/main/resources´ in the web app root folder.

Therefore you should create a new folder `resources` within `src/main/resources` and put the `js/` and `css/` folders there:

- `src/main/resources/resources/js/`
- `src/main/resources/resources/css/`

and modify `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/resources" />`

or `resources/js/` and `resources/css/` folder in `src/main/webapp`

- `src/main/webapp/resources/js/`
- `src/main/webapp/resources/css/`

and leave the spring configuration unchanged